# Automate a process

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that was taken using a balloon. The maximum altitude of the balloon was around 250m and then it was brought down. My data on altitude looks like the one below:

```
Altitude
-2.3
-1.1
0.0
1.6
2.3
0.8
1.6
4.7
5.4
9.7
**12.0
11.5
15.9**
..
..
..
248.1
249.7
252.4
250.5
251.6
252.4
252.4
**246.1
248.5
239.8
238.8**
..
..
..
1.4
0.6
0
-0.5
```

I want to make a new column in my csv file for my altitude that starts with 0 and increases until 250 and then starts decreasing until it reaches 0 without irregularity. All the negative values I'd like to change it to 0 and values greater than 250 to 250. Most of the remaining values stay as it is. However, if you look at the bold value for example, I want 11.5 to change to 12(the former value) and 248.5 to 246.1 so that the trend is increasing and decreasing respectively. How can I automate this process?

Comment: What have you tried? The question is off-topic unless you mention some of your own efforts to solve the automation problem.

Comment: What about the 6th and 7th rows of data?  Should they be changed to something?  What if the balloon is really bouncing up and down?  What kind of information are you trying to get out of this? How many ups or downs in row would constitute a change in direcdtion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not going to answer this directly for you but I will give you a structure so that you can develop a solution for yourself. What follows relies almost exclusively on the `IF` function, so you need to be familiar with this and the use of nesting one `IF` inside another.

Your problem has a number of different aspects to it, so helper columns deal with these different aspects.

The first helper column deals with your first set of corrections - ie correcting altitudes which are less than zero or greater than 250m. A nested `IF` formula of the form

```
=IF(condition1,result1,IF(condition2,result2,result3))
```

with suitable choices for the `condition` and `result` arguments can be used for this.

Implicitly, at least, you want to divide the sequence of altitude values into three phases: `Ascent`, `Peak Altitude` and `Descent` because your second set of corrections prohibits a decrease in altitude in the ascent phase and an increase during descent. A second helper column, which calculates values of `A`, `P` or `D` to represent these phases is used. You will need to think carefully about the formula that can be applied to calculate this helper column but in words:

1. If the preceding altitude is in the ascending phase, then the current altitude is in the ascending phase if its altitude is below the peak altitude, otherwise it will be in peak altitude phase.
2. If the preceding altitude is in peak altitude phase, then if the current altitude is less than peak altitude it is in the descending phase, otherwise it will be in the peak altitude phase.
3. If the preceding altitude is in the descending phase then the current altitude will also be in the descending phase.

Each of 1., 2. and 3. involve initial tests for the phase of the preceding altitude, and this is just the value contained in the preceding row of this second helper column. Denoting this value as `PrAltPh` then the logic of the initial tests can be written as

```
=IF(prAltPh="A",calculation1,IF(prAltPh="P",calculation2,"D"))
```

There are a few points to note here:

- `calculation1` implements this part of 1., above: *the current altitude is in the ascending phase if its altitude is below the peak altitude, otherwise it will be in peak altitude phase* so this calculation is a formula that delivers either "A" or "P" according to the value of the current altitude (Hint: use another `IF` and use the first helper column for the current altitude).
- `calculation2` implements this  part of 2., above: *if the current altitude is less than peak altitude it is in the descending phase, otherwise it will be in the peak altitude phase* so again another formula that delivers either "P" or "D"
- No phrase of the form `IF(PrAltPh="D",...,...)` is necessary in the formula given above because the three phases represented by "A", "P" and "D" are mutually exclusive. The two `IF`s explicitly test whether `PrAltPh` equals "A" or "P" and if both tests fail then the phase associated with the current altitude must automatically be "D"
- For the first altitude reading, there is no phase set for preceding
  altitude (because there is no preceding altitude), so rather than
  using a formula to set the first altitude's phase value set it
  manually to whichever of "A", "P" or "D" you think is appropriate.

Work out what the formulae for `calculation1` and `calculation2` should be and plug these into the nested `IF` above. Then insert into the second cell of the second helper column. Copy the formula down for the rest of the altitude values. Check the results are what you expect and, if not, either figure out what the formula should be or come back with what you tried and ask another question.

A third helper column, can be used to make the corrections that no reductions in altitude are allowed during the  ascent phase and no increases during the descent. This final helper column is another formula which calculates the second set of corrections. which depend on the phase (second helper column) of the current altitude (first helper column) and its relationship to the preceding corrected value (preceding value in the the third helper column). Again, in words:

1. If the current phase is ascending then,  if the current altitude is not less than the preceding corrected altitude then the current corrected altitude is set equal to the current altitude, otherise it is set to the previous corrected altitude.
2. If the current phase is descending then, if the current altitude is not greater than the preceding corrected altitude then the current corrected altitude is set equal to the current altitude, otherwise it is set to the previous corrected altitude.
3. If the current phase is at peak altitude then the current corrected altitude is set equal to the current altitude.

Using `CurAlt` to denote the current altitude and `CurAltPh` to denote the phase associated with this altitude, development of the formula for the corrected current altitude follows a familiar pattern as:

```
`=IF(CurAltPh="A",calculation3,IF(CurAltPh="D",calculation4,CurAlt))`
```

where `calculation3` and `calculation4` each deliver either `CurAlt` or the preceding corrected altitude according to how these two values compare with each other. Again there is the problem of setting a corrected altitude value in this third helper column for the first altitude value but it should be fairly obvious what value should be used.

Whilst I hope that the above gets you going down the right track, there are at least a couple of pitfalls to be wary of:

- If you hard code the peak altitude as 250 in the formula for `calculation2` above, you will run into problems if your altitude never    attains this height. To see this adjust your data and see what happens.
- If your data goes above 250, then below, then above again, the    descent phase will start with the below 250 reading and, as a result, apply the no increase rule to the second (and any subsequent) altitude readings above 250. This might not be the behaviour you want. For example, you may want all altitudes between the first and last that are above 250 to be counted as belonging to the peak altitude phase.

There are solutions to deal with both issues but they do underline the importance of testing solutions against all possible cases that might be encountered.

The picture illustrates, complete with chart and some exaggerated data, what a solution based on the above structure could look like.

[image]

Comment: I got the phase part. However, i couldn't figure out the formula for `calculation4` and `calculation4`.

Comment: `calculation 3` is `=MAX(CurAlt, PrevAlt)`, `calculation 4` similar but uses the `MIN()` function instead.